# About MVC4 User Input,How to don't rely on entity(model) input validation?

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

Vs2012 /WebSite Razor2 Development mode, can use the following methods validation?

So how to use the MVC similar method?

```
// Setup validation
Validation.RequireField("email", "You must specify an email address.");
Validation.RequireField("password", "You must specify a password.");
Validation.Add("password",
    Validator.StringLength(
        maxLength: Int32.MaxValue,
        minLength: 6,
        errorMessage: "Password must be at least 6 characters"));

<ol>
    <li class="email">
        <label for="email" @if (!ModelState.IsValidField("email"))
            {<text>class="error-label"</text>}>电子邮件地址</label>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="@email" @Validation.For("email")/>
        @* 将任何用户名验证错误写入页中 *@
        @Html.ValidationMessage("email")
    </li>
    <li class="password">
        <label for="password" @if (!ModelState.IsValidField("password")) {<text>class="error-label"</text>}>密码</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" @Validation.For("password")/>
        @* 将任何密码验证错误写入页中 *@
        @Html.ValidationMessage("password")
    </li>
    <li class="remember-me">
        <input type="checkbox" id="rememberMe" name="rememberMe" value="true" checked="@rememberMe" />
        <label class="checkbox" for="rememberMe">记住我?</label>
    </li>
</ol>
<input type="submit" value="登录" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps if you are trying to avoid using the model, you can use strongly typed ViewModel objects that utilize the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations library. You can annotate each property of your ViewModel classes and then Razor will read the annotations and do the proper validation. Then, in your controller, you simply check if (ModelState.IsValid) before doing your work on postback. Than use AutoMapper to map the ViewModel properties to the Model.

Here is an example of a ViewModel using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations:

```
public class PropertyViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public PropertyType PropertyType { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Address { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string City { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public StateFullName State { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Zip { get; set; }
}
```

Add this to your View:

```
@model PropertyViewModel
```